# Why aren't people named after the rabbis from the Talmud?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, names

Besides a couple names (ex: Akiva, Ashi) you don't really see many people over the course of history who have names that originated from the Talmud- ie "Huna", "Abaye", "Zevid", "Puppa" etc.

Why do you think think this? (other than someone maybe not liking these names for their child)  These members of Chazal are literally *gedolim she'b'gdolim*!

Comment: I know an Abaye

Comment: @DoubleAA haha really? Can you maybe add some additional tags to the original question so it might be easier to find?

Comment: Why's that funny?

Comment: There's a Hassidic sect called "Puppa". I see their school buses in my neighborhood frequently. Maybe  the rebbe or the town was named after Puppa.

Comment: @DanF, the Hassidic sect is named (as they all are) after a city. In this case the Hungarian city of Pápa, with a Yiddish pronunciation.

Comment: @Yishai And maybe the town was named after Puppa, and the Hungarians couldn't pronounce it correctly?